# Can't set the page size using apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I tried the code here: [How to set page orientation for Word document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20188953/how-to-set-page-orientation-for-word-document) but I can't set the page.

```
XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();

CTDocument1 document = doc.getDocument();
CTBody body = document.getBody();

if (!body.isSetSectPr()) {
     body.addNewSectPr();
}
CTSectPr section = body.getSectPr();

if(!section.isSetPgSz()) {
    section.addNewPgSz();        //in this part, the "addNewPgSz()" does not appear
}
CTPageSz pageSize = section.getPgSz(); //this part, the "CTPageSz" is not available
```

I am using apache poi 3.17, I added all the libraries, where could be the problem? Please help. Thank you!

Comment: What means "the "CTPageSz" is not available"? Are you saying that `section.getPgSz();` returns `null` although `section.isSetPgSz()` is true?

Comment: See if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34897091/error-in-ctpagesz-class-using-apache-poi-java-netbeans-word-document solves your issue

Comment: Thank you! ooxml-schemas was the problem.. Got it fixed! Thank u so much :)